# Why the testng assign the property a to the same address?

Tags: java, testng

There are 2 classes, Base.java and Demo.java.

```
public class Base {

    public A a;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        a = new A();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " a -------" + a);
    }
}
```

Following is the Demo.java

```
public class Demo extends Base {
    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("11111111111");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("2222222222");
    }
}
```

Following is my xml:

```
<suite name="Integration" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
    <test name="1">
        <classes>
            <class name="example.Demo"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

When I type the command:

```
mvn clean test
```

the output is the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
TestNG-test=1-2 a -------example.A@18e702c8
TestNG-test=1-1 a -------example.A@18e702c8
2222222222
11111111111
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.278 sec
```

We could see there are 2 threads: `TestNG-test=1-2` and `TestNG-test=1-1`, but why does the variable "a" in 2 different threads have the same address "example.A@18e702c8"?

I thought `beforeMethod()` in Base.java would be invoked 2 times as there are two methods in the Demo.java, so the variable "a" should have 2 different independent values.

But in fact, it does not execute like I thought. Could someone help to resolve it?

Comment: think a variable as global variable and each test is executed parallel

Comment: yes, a is global variable, that is why all paralleled tests will share the same address ?